# Hoisting in javascript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I asked a question before and somebody give me a guide and I read it and I saw this

```
  var temp = setTimeout,
  setTimeout = function() {};
```

He said that temp will be undefined due to JavaScript hoisting and I dont understand why
Its not should be like that?

```
    var temp;
    temp = setTimeout;
    setTimeout = function() {};
```

so why its undefined?

Comment: To anyone answering, note the comma in the first block of code after "setTimeout". +1

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  `temp` is declared and then initialized to the undefined value `setTimeout` before `setTimeout` is declared and defined.  But defining `setTimeout` also sounds like a really bad idea, at least in a browser environment, as that is a symbol already used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not the same. Your [multiple `var` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) also declares `setTimeout`:

```
var temp = setTimeout,
    setTimeout = function() {};
```

which is hoisted to

```
var temp; // = undefined
var setTimeout; // = undefined
temp = setTimeout;
setTimeout = function() {};
```

Comment: I suspected this is what was going on, but I wasn't sure I'd be able to explain it as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a variable declared with the keyword **var** is its current execution context. When a variable is initialized, javascript engine by default initializes the variable to *undefined*. 
Like,

```
var a; //it initializes to undefined
```

Again when you use a variable before declaring them, its now on running context. 
For Example:

```
console.log(a);
var a=10;
```

in this case, javascript engine runs the code in following ways,

```
var a; // a = undefined
console.log(a); // 
a =10;
```

it pick up the variable declaration to the top of the execution context but not its value. This is called hoisting that you have already probably known.

In your case:

```
  var temp = setTimeout,
  setTimeout = function() {};
```

from function(){}, suppose we get value =10;

now your code seems like:

```
var temp = setTimeout,
setTimeout = 10;
```

but javascript does the thing in the following way,

```
var temp; // temp = undefined
var setTimeout; // setTimeout = undefined
temp = setTimeout; // here temp is undefined as setTimeout is undefined
setTimeout =10;
```

it keep up all declared variable to the top of stack (Not its value but initializes to undefined).

If you want to learn more, visit the following link:

[medium: what is javascript hoisting](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-what-is-hoisting-in-javascript-a63c1b2267a1)

[scotch: understand hoisting in javascript](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript)